# How to set the image directory name in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing an Android application for thumbnail image in grid-view. I'm creating another class for set the image directory name in String format.

My all images save in `Gallery -> My photos` OR by default `sdcard -> Images -> My photos` so I'm using this path String `path="/sdcard/Images/My photos/"` then I tried different `path="/sdcard/My photos/";` but then when I run the application and the application is crashed and display the  error message like:

> path is not valid Please set the image directory name

Which path is set to directory name in String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/Images/My photos/img.jpg", options);

imgView.setImageBitmap(bm)
```

Comment: I USE this path + "/Images/My photos/ my code is working fine.Thanks a  lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Comment: Yes i used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in another class and the string strPath  like File directory = new File(
    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
      + File.separator + AppConstant.strPath);

Answer (score 0):

```
File mDirectory = new File("/sdcard/MyPhotos/");
mDirectory.mkdirs();
File outFile = new File(mDirectory, filename);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

Comment: Still my file path is in_vallid why so.